# Autocmd in vim not calling the function

Tags: python, vim, autocmd, vim7.3

```
" Python logger-print and vice-versa

function! SetPrintLogMaps()
    echom "called"
    nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>lp "lyy"lp"l5cawprint^[
    nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>ll "lyy"lp"lcawself.logger.info(^O$)^[
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite,BufRead *.py :call SetPrintLogMaps()
```

I have this autocmd so that the mappings are set only when a python script is read or written. But the function is not being called when I open any python script.

I've just found that if I am opening the script from command-line like
`vim test.py` it is not working.
But if I just open `vim` and then execute `:e test.py` the function is being called.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `FileType` event:

```
augroup myPythonStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python call SetPrintLogMaps()
augroup END
```

Better, put this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>lp "lyy"lp"l5cawprint^[
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>ll "lyy"lp"lcawself.logger.info(^O$)^[
```

and call it a day.